# Is there any validation expression like unique: in laravel that return true if value exist in database for the attribute

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-validation

Is there any validation expression like unique: in Laravel that return true if value  exist in database for the :attribute like. Have a look at email attribute:-

```
$data=[]
$rules= ['email': 'exist_in_database']
$validator=Validator::make($data,$rules);
if($validator->passes()){
//do something
}else{
//error
}
```

==>unique: return false if value exist

if no such validation exist that how to make custom validator by extending Validator for this problem? Please help

Comment: check the `exists` rule http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-exists

Answer (score 1):

Yes and the syntax for it is `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`

In your case,

```
$rules= ['email' => 'unique:users,email'];
```

For further docs, check [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique).

Comment: ok, but this is for given the custom column name to check for unique, but
as per the problem i need an alternative for this code as validation:- consider it


$user=User::where('email','=',$given_email) ->get();
if($user->exists()){
return true;
}else{
//not validated
}

if not such validation exists then how to make a custom one for that

Comment: $rules= ['email' => 'exists:users,email'];

that works

Answer (score 0):

I use this to validate any unique field, in this case Email ID which belongs to USERS table:

```
 if (!empty($id)) {
     $rules['email'] = 'required|email|min:6|max:75|unique:users,email,' . $id . ',id,deleted_at,0000-00-00 00:00:00';
} 
else {
    $rules['email'] = 'required|email|min:6|max:75|unique:users,email,NULL,id,deleted_at,0000-00-00 00:00:00';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question "How to create a new Validator".
Here is how:

```
Validator::extend('validator_name', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){

// whatever code you want here, I suggest you play with the parameters

// below there is an example of validation using regex
  return preg_match('/^[\pL\h]+$/u', $value);
});
```

To make this code work, create a ValidatorServiceProvider and put this code inside boot() function, then register the provider in your app.php like this:

`App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,`